# how to find min and max of dice roll program in python

Tags: python

```
import random
print(' \t Welcome rolling dice game\n ')


while True :
 input(' Press any key to roll')
 roll=random.randint(1,6)
 print(roll)

 stop= input( ' you want to roll. again ? \n if yes then enter y \n if not then enter n\n ')
 if stop=='y':
   continue
 elif stop=='n':
   break


print(' Thanks for Playing:')
```

Comment: You can format your code for a better readability.

Comment: What's the problem you are having? Do you want to get all the rolls by the user and get the max and min of that?

Comment: Creating a few variables to save what you get ought to be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
min = 6
max = 0
while True :
   input(' Press any key to roll')
   roll=random.randint(1,6)
   print(roll)

   if roll>max:
      max = roll
   if roll<min:
      min = roll
```